# Inexplicable gap in between my divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate the BBC News site and I have this weird styling problem.
[Here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDkID.png)

I always get this gap in between two of my divs.
Here is the code I used. Not sure how I am supposed to go about getting rid of that space. tried setting margin and padding to 0 but that didn't work.

Here is the code:

```css
body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }
            #topbar{
                height: 40px;
                width: 1000px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            #logo{
                float: left;
                margin-top: 8px;
                margin-right: 8px;
                
            }
            .topbarsections{
                float:left;
                border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #signin-image{
                float: left;
                width: 30px;
                margin-top: 7px;
                margin-left: 8px;
            }
            #signin-text{
                float: left;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 90%;
                color: #333333;
                position: relative;
                top: 13px;
                padding-right: 80px;
            }
            .topbar-menu{
                float: left;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #333333;
                font-size: 90%;
                padding: 13px 15px 0 15px;
                height: 27px;
                
                
            }
            #more-arrow{
                height: 13px;
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
            #search-box{
                background-color: #E4E4E4;
                margin: 8px 0 0 10px;
                border: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 140px;
                float: left
                
            }
            #magnifying-glass{
                margin-top: 8px;
                height: 26px;
                
            }
            .clear{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #news-bar{
                background-color: #BB1919;
                width: 100%;
                height: 70px;
            }
            #inner-news-bar{
                background-color: #BB1919;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 1200px;
                height: 70px;
            }
            #news-bar h1{
                color: white;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 10px;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 45px;
            }
            #menu-bar{
                background-color: #A91717;
                width: 100%;
                height: 35px;
            }
            #inner-menu-bar{
                background-color: #A91717;
                width: 1200px;
                height: 35px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .menu-bar-sections{
                float: left;
                border-right: 1px solid #BB4545;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right:8px;
                position: relative;
                top: -5px;
            }
            .menu-bar-sections a{
                float:left;
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .menu-bar-sections a:hover{
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            #menu-bar-more-section{
                border-right: none !important;
                
            }
            #down-arrow{
                float: left;
                height: 13px;
                position: relative;
                top: 2px;
                margin-left: 2px;
            }
            #page-container{
                width: 1200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            h2{
              
            }
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="topbar">
            
            <img id="logo" src="images/bbclogo.png">
            
            <div id="signin-div" class="topbarsections">
                
                <img src="images/singin.PNG" id="signin-image">
                <span id="signin-text">Sign in</span>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="topbarsections topbar-menu">
                
                News
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="topbarsections topbar-menu">
                Sports
            </div>
            
            <div class="topbarsections topbar-menu">
                Weather
            </div>
            
            <div class="topbarsections topbar-menu">
                Shop
            </div>
            
            <div class="topbarsections topbar-menu">
                Earth
            </div>
            
            <div class="topbarsections topbar-menu">
                Travel
            </div>
            
            <div class="topbarsections topbar-menu">
                More
                <img id="more-arrow"src="images/more-arrow.PNG">
            </div>
            <div class="topbarsections">
                
                <input id="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <input type="image" id="magnifying-glass" src="images/glass.PNG">
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="news-bar">
            <div id="inner-news-bar">
        
                <h1>NEWS</h1>
        
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="menu-bar">
            <div id="inner-menu-bar">
        
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">Home</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">Video</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">World</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">US & Canada</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">UK</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">Business</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">Tech</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">Science</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">Stories</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">Entertainment & Arts</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections"><a href="">Health</a></p>
                <p class="menu-bar-sections" id="menu-bar-more-section"><a href="">More</a><img src="images/down-arrow.PNG" id="down-arrow"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="page-container">
            
            <div id="main-article">
                <h2>Technology</h2>
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
```

Comment: where is the html?

Comment: I added the html.

Comment: Could it be related to the `<h2>`margin somehow?

Comment: @OlivierKrull when I get rid of it there is no gap

Comment: @OlivierKrull How can I as an H2 without having that gap

Comment: ok then css: h2 {margin : 0} or better : #main-article h2 {margin: 0;}

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete, hence irrelevant, as it does not reproduce the bug. Please edit your snippet into a live one ([mcve]), making sure it reproduces the described behavior. Also make sure you state in clear the desired behavior.

Comment: Andrei is right if you want a complete and correct answer

Comment: I put in the full code. Sorry first time using this.

Comment: @GermainTchuinkam, ***because*** it is the first time, you need to take it slowly. You didn't pay attention to my previous comment. While your snippet is now Complete and verifiable, it is far from Minimal. Please add only relevant code for your question, not the entire page. Use the `<>` button and add the markup to HTML panel, CSS to CSS panel and any script to JavaScript panel. Run it and make sure it works. I'll just do it for you, but do it yourself next time.

Comment: well margin:0 does the trick https://jsfiddle.net/z8f1kuec/

Comment: @OlivierKrull When I use margin:0; it just moves the Technology to the right side of screen. but there is no more gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "gap" you mean the space above the heading "Technology", @Olivier Krull is right: that's the default margin of the `h2` header.

You can simply add this CSS rule to set it to zero:

```
#main-article > h2:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: When I added that the text got pushed to the write side of the screen despite having fixed the space.

Comment: There's some floating going on - add also `clear: both` to it to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you found the problem. The problem was the down arrow next to the more Idk what was wrong with it but when I took it our the issue got resolved.